# Error when sending email with jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to use email sending in jenkins. I leave default values, click on 'Test configuration' button and get error:

> Failed to send out e-mail
>
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   localhost, port: 25;   nested exception is:   java.net.SocketException:
>   Permission denied: connect
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)

What I missed? It's not working by default?

Comment: You can check in your gmail security if "less secure apps" in enabled. Only if its enabled, we can send an email

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I configured Jenkins with my gmail account using the settings as given in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Sadly Google now blocks this access by default, I believe it can be enabled by reducing the security in gmail settings.

Comment: where is email config in jenkins

Comment: Jenkins -> Configure Systems -> E-Mail Configuration

Answer (score 14):

I had  similar problem couldn't send email via zoho. The configurations were: [SMPT TLS Zoho Configurations](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html) 
I just need to change system admin address in jenkins configurations to the same one in email-notifications.

Here you can find the system admin e-mail:
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> System Admin e-mail address

Comment: Thank you!!  I've been hunting this easter egg for two days now.  Not sure why Jenkins accepts the smtp username/pass and then decides to use the jenkins email as username instead of the one I've specified.  Thanks!

Comment: thank your this comment i think my zoho email SMTP broken now its fixed

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having issues with emails in Jenkins, a lot has changed since then.

If you have a custom domain name for g-mail and it requires a 2-step authentication to login, for example `you@yourcompany.com`,

**SMTP server** should still be `smtp.gmail.com`

**Default user e-mail suffix** should be `@yourcompany.com`

Because Google no longer allows you to simply use your default e-mail password to login via any outside apps, in this case Jenkins. It is a lot more secure to let Google create a custom password for Jenkins rather than turning off G-Mail's security features to allow Jenkins access to your account.

Create the *App Password* here:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Use the generated password in `Jenkins` -> `Configure Systems` -> `E-Mail Configuration`

Answer (score 4):

I was also struggling with this error. Here is how I resolved it.

**1. Google account settings:**

Go to Gmail account settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access -> Enable IMAP (This is to enable both IMAP & SMTP settings)

Check [configuration details](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&visit_id=636711348934015376-1929736174&rd=2) that are mentioned as:

- Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.gmail.com
- Requires SSL: Yes
- Requires TLS: Yes (if available)
- Requires Authentication: Yes
- Port for SSL: 465
- Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

(Rather than going with settings mentioned by anyone, please checkout your account for this info as settings/configurations keep on changing. )

**2. Jenkins (2.121.3) settings:**

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Scroll down to E-mail Notification tab -> Advanced

- Use SMTP Authentication: checked
- User Name: <your gmail id>
- Password: <your password>
- Use SSL: checked
- SMTP Port: 465
- Reply-To Address: Optional (I left it blank. You can give any email id you want)
- Charset: UTF-8

Enable "Test configuration by sending test e-mail", give test email id and hit "test configuration" button

**NOTE:**

1. Make sure you are connected to open network (that is not antivirus protected or antivirus may block your emails). I used my phone internet instead of office internet for testing this.
2. I didn't change any McAfee settings for doing this. Just switch your internet to open one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no SMTP server running on localhost or you don't have the permission to connect to it.

Check the configuration of Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have SMTP running on your machine, which is the usual state for Windows or Mac servers.

**To test this**, use any known mail-server for that, for example - if you have a gmail account, try this:

SMTP server: **smtp.gmail.com**

Default user e-mail suffix: **@something.something**

Sender E-mail Address: **your-mail@gmail.com**

If planning to use the mail-notifications as part of your build-process,
it is best to set the SMTP properly, or maybe move the Jenkins/Hudson server to a machine that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your provider blocks port 25.

In order to make a proper test

telnet smtp.gmail.com 25

If you receive an answer like this:

telnet: connect to address 74.125.206.108: Connection refused

You should go with smtp authentication as described in [harikrishna-pai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568541/1212830) answer

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and managed to resolved by following,

1. Generate Gmail App Password,
   [Gmail App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ4Qx.png)
2. In Jenkins use the app password,
   [Jenkin's Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS0Hp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue.
After witch hunting a lot, I found  a solution as below:

even turn on - less secure apps, I was struggling since 6 hour.
the second option:
And go to 
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and click Continue.

this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as i was using avast it blocked smtp mails so i disabled it and it worked

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.